# How does $\sqrt{y^2 + y^2} = 1$ give $y = -1/\sqrt{2}$ here?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I'm studying this problem:

[image]

and I cannot see the last step, how we go from $$\sqrt{y^2 + y^2} = 1$$ to $$y = -1/\sqrt{2}$$

When I try to solve this, I end up with:

$$y^2 + y^2 = 1^2 = 1$$
$$2y^2 = 1$$
$$y^2 = 2$$
$$y = \sqrt{2}$$

Comment: Well, you just do the algebra and solve for $y$.

Comment: I know it's a simple question, but I can't see how to do it.  I end up with $y = \sqrt{2}$

Comment: The problem is in the second to last step. You went from $2y^2 = 1$ to $y^2 = 2$ instead of $y^2 = \frac{1}{2}$. Moreover, if $y^2 = a$ then $y = \pm \sqrt{a}$, two solutions.

Comment: When you divide 1 by 2 you get 1/2. What is more, if you ghave y^2=1/2 yuo have positive or negative solution.

Comment: God, it was that simple.  Should I delete this question?

Comment: @nulliusinverba Once questions have answers they cannot be deleted, but it's a perfectly valid question anyway :)

Comment: Thanks BLAZE.  It has been a long time, but I am coming back to maths seriously as part of my computer science study.  I greatly appreciate everyone's help, and I do generally try to be extremely diligent before asking a question - it felt a little obvious this mistake, but actually I looked back over my notes and it was the equality of $\sqrt{1/2}$ and $1/\sqrt{2}$ that threw me originally.

Comment: I've added the latter question, here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1488761/why-does-sqrt1-2-1-sqrt2-but-sqrt2-3-neq-2-sqrt3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$2y^2 = 1$

at this point you need to divide both sides by 2:

$y^2 = \frac12$.  (You said $y^2 = 2$)

so

$y = \pm \sqrt{\frac 12}$  As y is negative

$y = - \sqrt{\frac 12} = \frac {-1}{\sqrt 2}$

Answer (score 0):

There are basically two interpretations here: either solve $\sqrt{y^2+y^2}=1$ to get $-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$.

Or, the other interpretation is: They didn't need to solve the equation $\sqrt{y^2+y^2}=1$. They just made the observation that $$\cos\left(\frac{5\pi}{4}\right)=\sin\left(\frac{5\pi}{4}\right)=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$

To see this, recall that the sine or cosine of $45^{\circ}$ or $\frac{\pi}{4}$ is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$.

So $\sin\left(\frac{5\pi}{4}\right)=\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}+\pi\right)$ (a translation in the negative $x$ direction).

By 'they', I mean the person who wrote the paper.

Answer (score 0):

The quadratic equation has two roots.. one positive, other negative. Negative value is to be chosen.