# Why does $\sqrt{1/2} = 1/\sqrt{2}$ but $\sqrt{2/3} \neq 2/\sqrt{3}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I can see that $\sqrt{1/2} = 1/\sqrt{2}$

My calculator also confirms I can change the denominator and the equality still holds.

But $\sqrt{2/3} \neq 2/\sqrt{3}$

Can someone explain why?  I need to get the concept here.

Comment: It may help if you review some square root basics as in the following link. Note that the square root of x is x raised to the power 0.5. http://www.mathwords.com/s/square_root_rules.htm

Comment: I certainly will, great link, thanks.

Comment: Never use a calculator as an indicator of anything

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is due to a step in the middle

Consider:

$\sqrt{1/2} = \sqrt{1}/ \sqrt{2} =1/\sqrt{2}$

Then

$\sqrt{2/3} = \sqrt{2}/ \sqrt{3} \neq 2/\sqrt{3}$

Comment: Very clear, thank you.

Answer (score 5):

In general $\sqrt{\frac{a}{b}}=\frac{\sqrt a}{\sqrt b}$ so if the numerator is $1$, then we have $\frac{\sqrt 1}{\sqrt b}=\frac{1}{\sqrt b}$

Answer (score 4):

Because $\dfrac{2}{\sqrt{3}} \cdot \dfrac{2}{\sqrt{3}} = \dfrac43$, not $\dfrac23$.

Or, if you prefer because $\sqrt{1}=1$, but $\sqrt{2}\neq 2$.

Answer (score 0):

The square root in this case is being applied for both the numerator and the denominator. Hence, you can split the num and den with the square root and calculate its value individually. However if the influence of the square root doesn't extend to the denominator or only applies to the denominator, it resembles the following  $\sqrt x/y$ or $x/\sqrt y$.

So, please watch out for the influence of the $\sqrt ..$ sign

$$\sqrt \frac{x}{y} = \sqrt x / \sqrt y$$